# Return a junction of rows with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

In my table I have this situation

```
|  id    |       book                      | reg   |    cif                       | nm  |    end        | nr |aa | bb  |    type     | 
|12134357|"Lv.2-Registro Geral (matrícula)"|"10001"|"1002414002024400386-90705793"|     |"Ataulfo Alves"|1877|"G"|"102"|             |
|12134356|"Lv.2-Registro Geral (matrícula)"|"10001"|""                            |"RUA"|"Ataulfo Alves"|1877|"G"|"102"|"Apartamento"|
|12134358|"Lv.2-Registro Geral (matrícula)"|"10001"|""                            |""   |"Ataulfo Alves"|    |"" |""   |"Apartamento"|
```

It`s possible to with one select(group by book and reg I return only one row with all informations? If I use DISTINCT she will group every equal value.

example of result:

```
|"Lv.2-Registro Geral (matrícula)"|"10001"|"1002414002024400386-90705793"|"RUA|"Ataulfo Alves"|1877|"G"|"102"|"Apartamento"|
```

tks

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6516a6/2)**

```
SELECT book,
       MAX("reg"), 
       MAX("cif"), 
       MAX("nm"), 
       MAX("end"), 
       MAX("nr"),
       MAX("aa"),
       MAX("bb"),
       MAX("type")
FROM  table1
GROUP BY book;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|                              book |                        max |                            max |   max |             max |  max | max |   max |           max |
|-----------------------------------|----------------------------|--------------------------------|-------|-----------------|------|-----|-------|---------------|
| "Lv.2-Registro Geral (matrícula)" | January, 01 10001 00:00:00 | "1002414002024400386-90705793" | "RUA" | "Ataulfo Alves" | 1877 | "G" | "102" | "Apartamento" |
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly are you trying to accomplish, but the following (really ugly) query will find the first nonempty value for each field and return all of them at once:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT "id"   FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("id"   || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "book" FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("book" || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "reg"  FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("reg"  || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "cif"  FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("cif"  || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "nm"   FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("nm"   || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "end"  FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("end"  || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "nr"   FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("nr"   || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "aa"   FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("aa"   || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "bb"   FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("bb"   || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT "type" FROM mytable WHERE coalesce(length("type" || '') > 0, false) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1);
```